# What is the lastest ftp request for comment

Tags: ftp, rfc

Is there exist rfc ftp specifcation fresher than [RFC 959](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959)?

Answer (score 0):

There were several extensions to FTP presented in later RFCs (rfc2228, rfc2389, rfc3659, rfc4217 and maybe some more) and they are enough for all current FTP-related needs. The only things not adopted as a standard but relatively wide-spread are implicit FTP on port 990 and Mode Z / compression.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the current status of [RFC 959](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959) in the status section at the top. If some later edition of the standard had replaced RFC 959, then there would be an entry "Obsoleted by" like there is an "Obsoletes" line for RFC 765, the previous version of the standard. However, other documents have since "Updated" the document (you could think of it as patches) and the documents are listed in the status section as "Updated by". There have also been a number of independent extensions that did not need to "update" the standard, like [RFC 2428](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2428). There is no reliably maintained index of such extension specifications besides the general RFC Index maintained by the RFC Editor.